# Updated graphics card does not update opengl32.dll

Tags: windows, delphi, opengl, textures

I've been trying to paint a texture on a square for the last week, but to no avail.  The square draws but no texture. 
I'm using OpenGL, Delphi XE3 & Windows 10.

The problem is the glGenerateMipmap function. 
My older version of opengl doesn't have the MipMap functions. 
So I replaced my card with something newer (OGL 4.6), which now has the functions. 
But it still doesn't work.

Problem is, the old opengl32.dll hasn't changed and it still doesn't have the functions.

So question is: 
How does the program find the MipMap functions? 
Is it possible to update the opengl32.dll with the new functionality somehow? 
Or does my program need to reference some other dll? 
Or should the winapi.opengl unit be updated?

According to khronos, a texture won't be drawn unless the MipMap is setup.   https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture

I'm trying to link to the glGenerateMipmap function in the DLL with:

```
  procedure glGenerateMipmap (target: GLenum); stdcall; external OpenGL32;
```

Which will compile but abort when it runs.

Comment: Installing new hardware doesn't magically install new software. You have to update your app's OpenGL DLL separately.

Comment: There's nothing magic about it.  When I update my drivers, I expect the drivers to get updated.

Answer (score 4):

It's good that `opengl32.dll` didn't change because it's not supposed to change. `opengl32.dll` is an OS component. The only thing that should ever touch this file is Windows itself, e.g., during an update.

Windows offers a generic OpenGL implementation which should always be available (may resort to software rendering). This generic implementation only supports OpenGL 1.1 which is why `opengl32.dll` only exports the basic OpenGL 1.1 API functions. In addition to that, other OpenGL implementations can be plugged into the system in the form of an Installable Client Driver (ICD). When installing drivers for your GPU, the GPU vendor will typically install and register such an ICD to run OpenGL using your GPU. When an OpenGL context is created via the [WGL APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/OpenGL/opengl-on-windows-nt--windows-2000--and-windows-95-98), the OS will [look for and load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/loading-an-opengl-installable-client-driver) a suitable ICD, and set up your OpenGL context to be talking to this ICD. The OpenGL 1.1 API functions exported in `opengl32.dll` really just forward to the ICD.

An ICD may (and typically does) offer additional functionality over the basic OpenGL 1.1 API that is exposed through `opengl32.dll`. To access such additional functionality, you have to manually load the respective functions via [`wglGetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress). Since writing all the code to, e.g., load the entire OpenGL 4.6 core profile API is quite tedious, one typically [uses a library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) such as GLEW or [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) to take care of that…

For Delphi, I guess [dglOpenGL](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/dglOpenGL) may be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This is roughly what I was assuming, but I was hoping a simple path forward.  I guess not.